# Response from Exchange Web Service is invalid XML

Tags: c#, web-services, exchangewebservices, microsoft365

I'm using the code below to authenticate with an Exchange-365 server and send an email, but I'm getting back "The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML".

The code is taken based on the code sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-send-email-messages-by-using-ews-in-exchange#send-a-new-email-message-by-using-the-ews-managed-api

I have my Entra application setup correctly.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;

namespace My.Sandbox.CoreConsoleApp;

internal class Program
{
    // ReSharper disable once IdentifierTypo
    private const string MyEntraAppClientId = "client-id";

    // ReSharper disable once IdentifierTypo
    private const string MyEntraAppTenantId = "tenant-id";
    private const string MyClientSecretValue = "client-secret-value";

    // ReSharper disable once IdentifierTypo
    private const string MyEntraAppRedirectUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient";
    private const string Outlook365EndpointUrl = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";

    /// <summary>
    ///     Specifies the primary mailbox against which operations should be performed. Useful in scenarios involving
    ///     multiple mailboxes or delegate access. Ensures accurate handling of tasks by directing requests
    ///     to the intended mailbox, facilitating secure and contextually relevant operations within Exchange environments.
    /// </summary>
    // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
    // ReSharper disable once IdentifierTypo
    private const string Headers_XAnchormailbox = "X-AnchorMailbox";

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => ConnectUsingAppOnlyAuthentication("my-email-address@My2.onmicrosoft.com")).Wait();
    }

    private static async Task ConnectUsingAppOnlyAuthentication(string accountAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            var authResult = GetToken();

            // Configure the ExchangeService with the access token
            var ewsClient = new ExchangeService
            {
                Url = new Uri(MyEntraAppRedirectUri),
                Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken),
                ImpersonatedUserId =
                    new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, accountAddress)
            };

            // ReSharper disable once CommentTypo
            //Include x-anchormailbox header
            ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add(Headers_XAnchormailbox, accountAddress);

            var email = new EmailMessage(ewsClient);
            email.ToRecipients.Add("test-target-email@gmail.com");
            email.Subject = "HelloWorld";
            email.Body = new MessageBody("This is the first email I've sent by using the EWS Managed API.");
            await email.SendAndSaveCopy();
        }
        catch (MsalException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($@"Error acquiring access token: {ex}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($@"Error: {ex}");
        }

        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Hit any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    private static AuthenticationResult GetToken()
    {
        // Using Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0
        var applicationBuilder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(MyEntraAppClientId)
            .WithClientSecret(MyClientSecretValue)
            .WithTenantId(MyEntraAppTenantId)
            .Build();

        // The permission scope required for EWS access
        var ewsScopes = new string[] { Scope.Outlook365_Default.Value };

        // Make the token request
        return applicationBuilder.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Represents an OAuth scope, which determines the resources and application can access
    ///     and the actions it can perform.
    /// </summary>
    [DebuggerDisplay("{Value}")]
    internal class Scope
    {
        #region constructors

        private Scope(string value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        #endregion

        #region properties

        public string Value { get; }

        #endregion

        #region static members

        // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
        public static readonly Scope Outlook365_Ews_AccessAsUser_All =
            new("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All");

        /// <summary>
        ///     The default scope for Exchange Online ("https://outlook.office365.com/.default")
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly Scope Outlook365_Default =
            new("https://outlook.office365.com/.default");

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlAsyncCheckReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read(XmlNodeType nodeType)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadXmlDeclaration(EwsServiceXmlReader reader)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadXmlDeclaration(EwsServiceXmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadPreamble(EwsServiceXmlReader ewsXmlReader)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(EwsServiceXmlReader ewsXmlReader, WebHeaderCollection responseHeaders)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponseXml(Stream responseStream, WebHeaderCollection responseHeaders)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(IEwsHttpWebResponse response)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.<InternalExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.<InternalCreate>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.<InternalSend>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

Comment: Does AuthResult have valid results?  It is sending an HTTP Request and should get back 200 OK if successful and 400/500 error if fails.  A failure will not produce an exception if you get back a response.  The exception will only occur if the connection does complete.  Your connection could complete but the credentials are bad and then you will get back a response with an error code and not exception.

Comment: I never used "entra URL" only exchange url

Comment: Thanks for replying @jdweng. I'm not getting and HTTP response code with authResult -the object does not have this field. However, I AM getting back an access token with a valid future expiration date.

Comment: Hey @T.S. - I worked all of this out from the code samples and guides on Microsoft's website. Note that I'm using the Microsoft-365 Exchange endpoint at https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx - the other URL is a mandatory redirect URL that I have to use despite this being a desktop app.

Comment: Where are you adding the message body?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/hh532564(v=exchg.80)

Comment: I happen to work on EWS for 10 years. Last year refactored from basic to OAuth, When you do this, a lot depends on the OAuth setting in microsoft. There are 3 styles of auth - Delegated, Application, ROPC. Your application seem connecting as the service oauth configured for "Application". So, make sure your EWS Oauth account configged as "Application". Make sure you get a valid token. If token is really valid, your config is probably good

Answer (score 0):

```
            var ewsClient = new ExchangeService
        {
            Url = new Uri(MyEntraAppRedirectUri),
            Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken),
            ImpersonatedUserId =
                new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, accountAddress)
        };
```

Isn't correct you have used the incorrect URL in ExchangeService constructor I think you meant to use

```
URL = new Uri(Outlook365EndpointUrl),
```

Because you have used the MyEntraAppRedirectUri the response you will get back for any SOAP request to that endpoint will be a HTML error.